# Chain of events in a deleter

Tags: python, python-descriptors

Suppose I have the following class with both a customer `deleter` for an attribute and on the instance itself:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self._is_open = None
    @property
    def is_open(self):
        return self._is_open
    @is_open.deleter
    def is_open(self):
        print("Using custom deleter!")
        del self._is_open
    def __delattr__(self, attr):
        print ('Deleting attr %s' % attr)
        super().__delattr__(attr)
```

And to call it:

```
>>> hello = Hello()
>>> del hello.is_open
Deleting attr is_open
Using custom deleter!
Deleting attr _is_open
```

It looks like it first calls the `__delattr__` on `is_open`, then it calls `@is_open.deleter`, then it calls `__delattr__` on `_is_open`. Why does the chain of events work like this for the deleters?

Comment: Looks like part of the question is missing?

Comment: @Aran-Fey updated. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Could you explain what part you don't understand and what output you would have expected instead? Because I don't really see any surprises here.

Comment: @wim basically, why it calls the deleter twice here, and why it calls that (the first time) before the attribute deleter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor). They are implemented via [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol).

The datamodel hook [`__delattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__) takes priority over the descriptor protocol. So, if you have a custom `__delattr__` method defined, then that will be called in preference to a property deleter.

In fact, it is the default implementation of `__delattr__` which will then go and invoke descriptors if necessary, you can verify this by commenting out the line with beginning with `super` (you should see that the property deleter now won't be called at all).

Armed with this reasoning, you can understand the chain of events which goes like this:

```
Deleting attr is_open
# the del statement `del hello.is_open` is directly invoking Hello.__delattr__,
# passing in attr="is_open" as argument

# Now, the implementation of `Hello.__delattr__` calls
# `super().__delattr__(attr)`, passing along the argument attr="is_open", which
# then invokes a descriptor for that attribute (i.e. the function
# `Hello.is_open.fdel` is about to be called)

Using custom deleter!
# This comes from within the property (`Hello.is_open`) deleter.

Deleting attr _is_open
# The implementation of the `is_open` deleter actually uses another del
# statement, i.e. `del self._is_open`. This invokes again `Hello.__delattr__`,
# passing attr="_is_open" as an argument. However, this time there is no
# descriptor with the name `_is_open` present so an attribute gets deleted from
# the instance namespace instead. Note that the attribute `self._is_open` was
# there in `self.__dict__` already because it gets created during the __init__
# method when `hello = Hello()` is executed.
```

It's important to notice that `__delattr__` received different argument the first and second time: `"is_open"` first then `"_is_open"` second.